# Python loop ascending values from list of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have list of dictionary like this:

```
list_data = [{'Date': '04-Oct-2018', 'Open': 10754.7, 'High': 10754.7, 'Low': 10547.25, 'Close': 10599.25, 'Shares Traded': 438202008, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 23711.57}, {'Date': '10-Jan-2019', 'Open': 10859.35, 'High': 10859.35, 'Low': 10801.8, 'Close': 10821.6, 'Shares Traded': 254365477, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 12031.26}]
```

Each Dictionary has Date,Open,High etc.
I want to the list to be sorted based on "High" - "Low" of dictionary.That is if list_data's first index value that is

```
{'Date': '04-Oct-2018', 'Open': 10754.7, 'High': 10754.7, 'Low': 10547.25, 'Close': 10599.25, 'Shares Traded': 438202008, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 23711.57}
```

has highest value of "High" - "Low" than it should be in last of the list_data.

Comment: Can you add an expected output and your code?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a pandas DataFrame here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sorted_list = sorted(list_data,key=lambda x: x["High"] - x["Low"], reverse=True)
```